# Sensitivity of Weibull survival model to early missing data

Tags: survival, missing-data, weibull-distribution

I have a few datasets of survival times that appears to be very well-modelled by Weibull distributions; I am mostly interested in whether $k$ is above, below or around 1.

However, there is a real chance that the data has a selection effect that leaves out some data points with small durations (the data is the survival time of societies, and clearly the literature may overlook particularly obscure and short-lived ones). As far as I can tell, removing some small duration data pushes $k$ upwards since it makes it look like the early time hazard is lower than it is.

Is there (1) a way of quantifying the magnitude of this effect (e.g. "if a fraction $x$ of points below $y$ are missing, $k$ is biased roughly as $f(x,y)$"), or (2) some principled way of dealing with it? For example, one could just translate the whole distribution so the smallest duration is $x_{min}+1$ ($+1$ to avoid the MLE fitting problems for Weibull for $x=0$); this looks very crude and potentially biased in the other direction to me. A more complex approach might to assume some functional form of the selection effect and try imputing extra data points, maybe even weighing together the resulting parameter estimates in a Bayesian way.

My analysis is pretty qualitative, so I am less interested in highly precise estimates than a way of reasoning about how solid conclusions can be in the face of this potential missing data.

Answer (score 2):

As you say,  one option is to switch to inference about only those that have survived x time units (i.e. condition on survival until you think you would know as records). If you assume that the data are truly Weibull, then that will even allow you to back calculate how many records with a failure time before the cut-off there should have been. That may be a useful sanity check to make.

If you have prior beliefs about how much data should be missing,  you could put your prior beliefs into sombre distributions and simulate missing data from these.

Or you could simulate missing data for various "what if scenarios".